how to make new installed gnome version 46.1 to be main?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (gnome) and downloaded and successfully installed new version 46.1. How can I make new version to start to work instead of 46.0?

Hi @Alexander. You will not have option to choose which version. When it is updated to 46.1. It will be the one.
